# Inline entity form complex and cardinatlity

Tags: 8, entities

I am adding an ief type field to my form with the following

```
    $form['inline_entity_form'] = [
        '#type' => 'inline_entity_form',
        '#op' => 'add',
        '#entity_type' => 'my_ent_type',
        '#bundle' => 'my_bundle',
    ];
```

I am sure this is something under my nose that i am missing but how do i force this to complex and set a cardinality for this instance?

Grateful for any pointers
Mathew

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the **type** to `inline_entity_form_complex` so that you have the following;

```
$form['inline_entity_form'] = [
    '#type' => 'inline_entity_form_complex',
    '#op' => 'add',
    '#entity_type' => 'my_ent_type',
    '#bundle' => 'my_bundle',
];
```

Got the pointer from the following answer. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/207582/9906