# How to use inline_entity_form in Drupal 8?

Tags: entities

I am building 2 custom Content entity types: one is a Node type representing a type of food, called "food". This food may have multiple varieties, which will differ with regards to specific details, so I wish to store information about the varieties in a separate database table, and to accomplish this I have defined a second entity type called "food_type" which serves to provide additional information related to the "food" node.

Within the Food form, I want to also fill out all the fields for the related food_type. I am trying to accomplish this using [inline_entity_form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form).

Following the [documentation](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/inline_entity_form/tree/README?id=a0f8bf8c59b5aa35d03383ec6a0b77791a8c149f&h=8.x-1.x), I have done the following things for food_type:

- Added a dependency of inline_entity_form in food_type.info.yml (there are no other dependencies)
- Created food_type/src/Controller/FoodTypeInlineEntityFormController.php, which contains the following code:

  ```
  namespace Drupal\food_type\Controller;

  /**
   * Controller routines for Food Type pages.
   */
  class FoodTypeInlineEntityFormController extends EntityInlineEntityFormController {

   /**
     * Overrides EntityInlineEntityFormController::entityForm().
     */
    public function entityForm($entity_form, &$form_state) {

      return parent::entityForm($entity_form, $form_state);
    }
  }
  ```
- Added the following code to `food_type_install()` in food_type.install:

  ```
  $entity_info['food_type']['inline entity form'] = array(
      'controller' => 'FoodTypeInlineEntityFormController',
  );
  ```
- Defined `'\Drupal\food_type\Controller\FoodTypeInlineEntityFormController::entityForm'` as the _controller default under entity.food_type.form in food_type.routing.yml

I cannot enable the food_type module. Attempting to do so yields the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Drupal\food_type\Controller\EntityInlineEntityFormController' not found in {directory}\sites\all\modules\custom\food_type\src\Controller\FoodTypeInlineEntityFormController.php on line 9

I assume this is caused because I do not include a `use` statement in FoodTypeInlineEntityFormController.php for `EntityInlineEntityFormController`. From Googling, it seems that such a statement is not used in example code that uses this module at all, and it's supposed to simply work when the inline_entity_form module is enabled. However, I for sure have inline_entity_form enabled and am still getting this error.

I would like to try a `use` statement, but the `EntityInlineEntityFormController` class does not seem to exist at all in the module code, as far as I can tell from searching. I am using 8.x-1.0-alpha6.

I am very new to drupal development and believe I am probably doing something else wrong, but I am completely at a loss here as to how to proceed or troubleshoot. Can anyone please help me or point me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It looks to me like the README did not get updated between the 7.x branch and the 8.x branch, so those instructions are probably totally wrong. I don't think the issue is you. I would suggest opening an issue in the issue queue.

Comment: I can try to write a full response later, traveling today. I recommend looking at the Drupal Commerce 2.x source. We implement IEF in two content entity base fields (product and orders)

Comment: Thank you both. I will look at the source for Drupal Commerce 2.x and will also open an issue.

Comment: @MattGlaman, I am wondering if your offer to write a full response is still on the table - I have been working through the Drupal Commerce code but am having difficulty understanding just how everything works together. This is probably because I am new to Drupal development, but the use of IEF is something I am struggling a lot with. Thank you very much for your initial response, if you don't have time I understand, but figured I would ask :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to implement Inline Entity form in D8, all you need to do is set your entity reference field to use the IEF widget - simple or complex. That is all. No additional work.

Here is how we set it up in Drupal Commerce for products, programmatically.

```
$form_display = commerce_get_entity_display('commerce_product', $product_type->id(), 'form');
$form_display->setComponent('variations', [
  'type' => 'inline_entity_form_complex',
  'weight' => 10,
  'settings' => [
    'override_labels' => TRUE,
    'label_singular' => 'variation',
    'label_plural' => 'variations',
  ],
]);
$form_display->save();
```

This tells the `variations` field, which is a Product Variation entity reference, to use IEF as the way to manage field values.