# Rendering two custom entity forms on the same page

Tags: 8, forms, entities

I have two custom entities, `Foo` and `Bar`. `Bar` has a has_one relationship with `Foo` through an `entity_reference` column.

I'd like an admin page that combines the forms of both entities. Ideally it would look something like:

```
Edit Foo

Name: ...
Description: ...

Bars

Name        Description        val1        val2
bar1        ...                ...         ...
bar2        ...                ...         ...
bar3        ...                ...         ...

[ add bar ]

[ save ]    [ delete ]
```

Ideally there would be inline `Bar` editing.

At the moment I have custom entities set up to use `_entity_form` and so they are edited on separate pages. This isn't ideal given their relationship. What's the best approach for combining forms in this way?

Many thanks.

Comment: You need Inline Entity Form, how to implement this in D8 see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/206684/how-to-use-inline-entity-form-in-drupal-8